# The number of real roots of a non-linear equation

Tags: exponential-function, roots, nonlinear-system

Given the equation $e^x=\frac{bx-a}{c+dx}$ where : $a,b,c,d \in R$ and $a+c=-1$, how can I prove that there are at most two real solutions? Graphically it's pretty clear to see since there is an exponential and a hyperbole, but formally how one should prove this? Many thanks.

EDIT : I am looking for positive solutions only.

EDIT :
[Prove a convex and concave function can have at most 2 solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2112108/prove-a-convex-and-concave-function-can-have-at-most-2-solutions) here I’ve found the answer to my question.

Comment: Here's a related question: how many intersections can a convex and a concave function have? Why? How about two convex functions or two concave functions?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2112108/prove-a-convex-and-concave-function-can-have-at-most-2-solutions Check here to find more.

Comment: It would be a fun proof to put both graphs on a sphere. I think stereographic projection will turn hyperbolas into ellipses.

Comment: Just FYI - "hyperbole" is wildly exaggerated speech, while a "hyperbola" is a conic section. "The most incredibly beautiful double-curve every produced by slicing a cone with a plane" would be a example of both.