# Looking for bibliography

Tags: reference-request, reference-works

I was going through : [Prove a convex and concave function can have at most 2 solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2112108/prove-a-convex-and-concave-function-can-have-at-most-2-solutions)

Despite the provided answers are correct and flawless, I was wondering if there was some literature about since I have to use this fact in my Thesis but my professor told me I should cite the source.

Comment: This is sufficiency specialized that don't think you'll find a published reference for this without a GREAT deal of work -- looking though dozens (maybe hundreds) of books in several university libraries, where it's likely to only be found (if at all) in one of a book's section/chapter exercise collections. Why not simply site the MSE answer? See [Do I cite Mathematics Stack Exchange in my thesis/paper?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4259/13130) and [Attributing contributions to academic work that occur in Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1580/49593)

Comment: Wow I didn’t know it could be possible to cite MSE. Anyway, I will ask my advisor.